# How to make A reverse pyramid

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to python and looking for a code to have the this output:

```
z
yy
xxx
wwww
vvvvv..
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```
n=10
for i in range(0, n):
    asci = (ord('z') - i + 1 )
    char = chr(asci)
    print (char*i)
```

see [Demo](https://repl.it/BE3W)